# Best way to describe this tree like multiple choice questions/answers algorithm in UML

Tags: java, algorithm, uml

There are two classes: Question and Answer. Instance of Question contains a list of Answers, each Answer points to a follow up Question. So each selected answer triggers a relevant next question until answer with no followup question is selected.

What would a UML diagram look like to best describe a questionnaire flow like this:

```
Q1: "Are you hungry?" [Yes, No]
  Yes->Q2: "What do you want to eat?" [Apple, Pear, Banana]
      Apple->Q4: "Green or red?" [Green, Red]
      Pear ->Q5: "Big or small?" [Big, Small]
  No ->Q3: "Are you thirsty?" [Yes, No]
      Yes->Q6: "What would you like to drink?" [Tea, Coffee, Water, Vodka]
          Tea  ->Q7: "Any sugar?" [1 spoon, 2 spoons, 3 spoons]
          Vodka->Q8: "Are you old enough for it?" [Yes, No]
```

A class diagram would describe relationship between the classes but not the question-answer flow.

Object diagram would have too much information about relationship between objects and the object's inner structure which would make it hard to read the question/answer flow which we are interested in.

Activity diagram would work well if questions were true or false, then the decision diamond shaped icon could be used for the true and false flow. But that wouldn't work if a question has 7 possible answers.

So my problem is to find the type of a diagram that would describe a flow like that in the most basic and clear way.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) because "_3. Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it._"

Answer (score 1):

Different diagrams are are used for different things and provide different  model of details. If you want to present relations between classes in you model then class diagram with two associations

```
Question 1 <-- answers --> 1..* Answer
Answer 1 <-- follow-up --> 0..1 Question
```

will be just fine (I intentionally do not say anything about the classes because I do not want to suggest implementation). In some tools like for example Enterprise Architect you can use this diagram to generate source code. Based on you question I think this is what you want.

If you on the other hand want to show control flow then you should use one of [behaviour diagrams](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ed/UML_diagrams_overview.svg/500px-UML_diagrams_overview.svg.png). Sequence or communication diagrams show how objects of your model interacts (which methods are used) with each other to implement specific use case. If you use states in you model then you can show it on state machine diagram.

Comment: I want to design questionnaires in UML based on this two classes. So state machine diagram is probably the closest but it doesn't allow to visually show how there's a question containing answers and answers pointing at other questions. I'm hoping to get a link to an example of a diagram.

Comment: That's why you should use two diagrams: one structural and one behavioral. Personally I would choose class diagram (this will show relations between answers and questions) and activity diagram [example](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/software-resolve-issue-uml-activity-diagram-example.html) to present logic.

Comment: What would you use for a graphical editor tool where a non technical user designs a diagram of a questionnaire which gets automatically converted into real instances of Question and Answer classes? Class and object diagrams are too bulky, technical and hard to read if the aim is to represent question/answer/question flow only.

Comment: I would probably develop one by myself or try to make use of existing finite state machine designer like [this one](http://madebyevan.com/fsm/). Nodes arcs questions, arcs are answers and whole state machine is a questionnaire. Btw. If I understand correctly the questions are single choice, not multiple choice, right?

Comment: So the point of my question is to verify that standard UML is not flexible enough to describe a flow like this before I invent my own way of doing it. For simplicity sake can start with single choice but really it's multiple choice.

Comment: Well.. no. It all depends on what aspect you want to show and how specific you want to be. I don't believe any system/program can be explained on my one diagram, that's why UML provides several different types. I also think we were talking about two things at one time. UML is for requirements and system specification. It's a tool for analysts, architects and developers. It will describe the system but won't generate you instances of questions and answers, it's the system job. 
To explain how the system will work (i.e. to client) I'd use screen mock-ups flow. It's like use case with UI flow

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are confused about the two possibilities of describing/modeling a "process flow":

1. at the type level where you describe a Q&A process type
2. at the object/instance level where you describe a specific Q&A process such as the one about Q1, Q2, etc. in your exmple.

You can use an object/instance-level model for describing exmples or for designing content.

But for designing a software application, you need to model at the type level. But the flow pattern of your problem is so simple that you don't need any behavioral model, really. It's entirely underdstandable from the class diagram (as sketched in Marek Adamek's answer) where the flow loops from a question to one of its possible answers, and then to this answer's follow-up question (and then to the next iteration).